# Name a method to get url safe unique links (.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

EDIT 1: Perhaps I wasn't very clear earlier. For the following scenario, I'd like to know the best/standard method.

I have a .NET 4 web application in which for various reasons I need to send unique links to our customers.(like password resets, invitations, acount verifications etc)

The link structure will be typically **mysite/some-action?key=some-unique-value**

What should I do to generate the **"some-unique-value"** part? Whatever the method, it shouldn't break my URL.

I found some questions on SO that came close to my need but couldn't quite nail it.
Also let me know if there is a better/standard way to implement this kind of feature. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use a GUID?

Comment: @Edward lot of people advice against the use of GUID in similar discussions in SO. So I didn't prefer them.

Comment: On what trust will you base the encryption and how to you plan to avoid replay attacks? You are probably of just as we'll by sending a unique key associated with some one time data in a db. Sending encrypted data in an otherwise unsafe URL (assuming this is not https) is not safe

Comment: @Devin I don't agree too much, a GUID don't break HTML and is pretty unique; you must save that the link navigation being used to prevent the reuse of link (sniffing o email reuse)

Comment: Why can't you URL encode whatever unique identifier you think fits your needs?

Comment: @RuneFS I asked this question because I wasn't sure of how to implement this kind of feature. Encryption was one method that came to my mind first. If you know a standard way, do let me know.

Comment: You would have be better of asking how to accomplish a goal then rather than asking a question about one very specific approach

Comment: @RuneFS yeah my bad actually. I just edited the question. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get a byte array - you can convert it to hex using:

```
BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
```

You might want to use a hash algorithm such as [SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) instead of encryption.

Comment: Thanks. I tried SHA256 now and it seems to fit the bill. Hope this is fairly secure and URL safe.

Comment: @Devin Just making sure I'm being clear: The URL-safeness is by converting to hex, that gives you only 0-9 and A-F (and "-"'s). The hash is just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to encrypt your query string parameters, [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx) is a good explanation.
([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236088/how-can-i-encrypt-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net-website))

Answer (score 0):

Use server.UrlEncode for encoding and Server.UrlDecode for decoding

```
Dim Url As String = "something.aspx?" 
Url & = "key = " & Server.UrlEncode("someUniqueValue")
```

EDIT: You don't have to decode the url string at the server as it is automatically decoded by asp.net and decoding it a second time may cause problems especially if your original url includes a '+' which will be decoded to a space.

Comment: this may solve step 2 of my problem. Step 1 is generating the unique value.

Comment: yes this will allow any special characters to pass to and from the browser to the server seamlessly.

Comment: Of course! My original concern was how to generate the unique value. Based on comments, I use SHA256.